# Shadow missing under the info box of the edit queue

Tags: bug, feature-request, design

The yellow box informing the users that their edits will be placed in a peer reviewed queue is missing the shadow under the bottom-right corner.

[image]

Comment: @bmike It’s not exactly a feature request, but every other yellow box has that shadow, so I think it was more like a slip than left like this on purpose.

Comment: I tagged it so the devs / designers would see it either way. :-) sharp eyes, too

Comment: @bmike Ah, OK, got it. Thanks!